# How can i change my current mysqli procedural way into pdo where i can call store procedure

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

i'm currently using mysqli procedure to write code which i want to change it in pdo because in mysqli i'm mysqli_escape_string whereas i dont how to change it in pdo
here is my mysqli attempt

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
        $id=$_GET['id1'];
        $result=GetWordsById(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$id));//Here GetWordsById is a function calling store procedure
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $word=$row['word'];
        $meaning=$row['meaning'];
        $synonym=$row['synonym'];
        $antonym=$row['antonym'];


        }
    ?>
```

below is my function.php

```
function GetWordsByID($id){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL GetWordsById($id)");//Here GetWordsById is my store procedure
    return $result;
}
```

Here i want to know how i can change both function and main php script calling function where i'm using mysqli_escape_string to pdo i'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

To PDO,
   your db connection file will look like this,

```
    <?
        $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";  // Enter your db username
    $password = "password";  // Enter your db password
    $dbname = "myDBPDO";   // Enter your db name

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Now comes your code,

```
<?

   if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
        $id=$_GET['id1'];
        $result=GetWordsById($id);//Here GetWordsById is a function calling store procedure
        if($result->fetchColumn()>0){

            $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $word=$row['word'];
        $meaning=$row['meaning'];
        $synonym=$row['synonym'];
        $antonym=$row['antonym'];


        }

}
```

and function,

```
function GetWordsByID($id){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=$conn->prepare("  ");//Here sql statement 
    $result->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: hii it is now showing me error in function.php syntax error, unexpected 'GetWordsById' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\function.php

Comment: i tried adding double quotes to store procedure call but it doesnt work either

Comment: Are you using this  'GetWordsById' ($id)' within the prepare statement?

Comment: 'GetWordsById' ($id)' is enclosed in prepared statement like you described        $result=$conn->prepare("GetWordsById' ($id) ");//Here sql statement like this still showing error

Comment: you are supposed to write sql statement in prepare statement.how come you can give GetWordsById' ($id) there ?   In order fetch data from database write sql statement like    `"SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE id = ' ".$id." '  " `

Comment: I'm working with store procedure wherein i'm writing query so i wanted to know how i can do the same with pdo

Comment: you can refer to this link https://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/